# How to know that satellite is already found or searching on android?

Tags: android, gps

I just want to show text "please wait" while app is searching for satellite and show "ready" when we found and connected to satellite.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getGpsStatus%28android.location.GpsStatus%29

Use `getGpsStatus` and the `GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX` status should tell you when you have received your first GPS status.

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 24.